# Revelation 2:10, is the tribulation of the ordinary believer 1/4 of Jesus'?

Tags: luke, revelation, mark

Revelation 2:10, (DRB):

> Fear none of those things which thou shalt suffer. Behold, the devil will cast some of you into prison that you may be tried: **and you shall have tribulation ten days**. Be thou faithful until death: and I will give thee the crown of life.

Mark 1:13, (DRB):

> And he was in the desert **forty days and forty nights,** and was tempted by Satan; and he was with beasts, and the angels ministered to him.

Luke 4:2, (DRB):

> For the space of **forty days;** and was tempted by the devil. And he ate nothing in those days; and when they were ended, he was hungry.

Is the tribulation of the ordinary believer 1/4 of Jesus'?, I mean, did Jesus suffer 4 times like the ordinary believer?

Comment: Interesting connection  +1.

Comment: Need to add an apostrophe after the last s in Jesus.  Otherwise the question seems strange.

Comment: @PerryWebb o.k, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The connection between Rev 2:10 (10 days) and the synoptic accounts of Jesus in Mark 1:13 & Luke 4:2 is tenuous at best.  I can see no verbal connection as the words are different:

- Rev 2:10 the **NOUN** is θλῖψις (thlipsis)  meaning persecution, affliction, distress, tribulation.
- Mark 1:13 & Luke 4:2 the **VERB** is πειράζω (peirazó) meaning try, tempt, test.

Therefore, I do not see any linguistic way these two sets of verses can be connected as they are discussing different matters at different times.